# How to unbrick Samsung Galaxy Y Duos

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I just wanted to upgrade my phone to jelly bean and I tried by viewing the tutorials. But when it got reboot it shows the samsung logo only. How can I make my phone working??

Comment: you need to describe how you tried to upgrade your phone to jelly bean. Which tutorial did you follow. What did you do exactly...otherwise it will be difficult to offer any help as we won't be able to pinpoint the actual issue.

Comment: at least you soft bricked it, you can try installing the stock rom again and trying the tutorial again, you might have missed something. It's also possible you did not use the correct rom to flash your device.